# How to style divs which do not have any elements in it?

Tags: html, css

I would like to know if I can select a `div` which does not have any elements in it in CSS.

For example:

HTML:

```html
<body>
    <!-- div with some elements inside of it -->
    <div>
        ...
    </div>

    <!-- divs with nothing inside of them -->
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</body>
```

If this was the `body` of my `HTML` code, I would like to select the last four empty divs.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: div::empty? [from mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) this select all empty divs

Comment: also, the 2 colons didn't work, but 1 colon did

Comment: what do you mean with 2 colons?

Comment: div::empty did not work, but div:empty did

Comment: yeah, my mistake div:empty is correct

Comment: I'll check if exists another similar question if no i'll provide an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:empty` pseudo-class.
It represents any element that has no children. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty)

```css
section{
  display:flex;
}
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
}

div:empty {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <!-- div with some elements inside of it -->
  <div>
    Text Text Text
  </div>

  <!-- divs with nothing inside of them -->
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```